# Spring cloud oauth2 enable revoke token endpoint

Tags: spring-security, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I need revoke token endpoint. It seems absent in spring framework, so I've added custom one. There are added two methods (`GET`, `DELETE`) with the same functionality (to play with that):

```
@FrameworkEndpoint
@RequestMapping(
    value = {"oauth"},
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
@Validated
public class RevokeTokenEndpoint {

  @Autowired
  private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
  @GetMapping(value = "revoke")
  public void revokeToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authorization != null && authorization.contains("Bearer")) {
      String tokenId = authorization.substring("Bearer".length() + 1);
      tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
    }
  }

  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
  @DeleteMapping(value = "revoke")
  public void revokeToken(Authentication authentication) {
    tokenServices.revokeToken(((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication
        .getDetails()).getTokenValue());
  }
}
```

If I try `GET` method, token is revoked successfully:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer e7683428-d06b-429a-9e76-91df9521c897" "http://localhost:8082/oauth/revoke"

2019-08-22 14:26:37.814 DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed 204 NO_CONTENT
```

in `DELETE` `method` case - no:

```
2019-08-22 14:28:53.551 DEBUG o.s.b.a.a.l.AuditListener - AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-08-22T11:28:53.550Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A8B4925366067778DC83CDE4066F1A62, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
```

### Question

Is there any recommendations how to make working `oauth/revoke` endpoint for the `DELETE` `method` (resolve `AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE` issue)?

### More Details

Please be informed, I tried similar functionality to `GET` for `DELETE` `method` also.

My security restrictions are:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/oauth/revoke")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to specify HTTP method explicitly in `antMatcher ` like, `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/oauth/revoke").permitAll()`?

Comment: No I didn't, I've just checked this way: `AuditEvent [timestamp=2019-08-27T11:01:23.821Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 7568A82D79230C146B52F24FECF0ED1A, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using as path `/oauth/token` instead, e.g.:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
@DeleteMapping(value = "token")
public void revokeToken(Authentication authentication) {
  tokenServices.revokeToken(((OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication
      .getDetails()).getTokenValue());
}
```